# C89: Access violation reading 0x00 (difficulty with malloc)

Tags: c, malloc, null-pointer

I am developing C89 on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Beta (Win 7). I don't think I'm using `malloc()` correctly. I am new to C, so please excuse the beginner question.

The goal of my program is to count the occurrence of words in `**argv` using a tree.

**hist.c**

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int i;
    struct tree *tree;
    tree = new_tree();

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        tree_add(tree, argv[i]);
    }

    tree_dump(tree);
    tree_free(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

**tree_add.c:**

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tree *tree_add(struct tree *tree, char *value) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        tree = new_tree();
        tree->value = value;
        tree->count = 0;
    }
    else if (tree->value == NULL) {
        tree->value = value;
    }
    else if (tree->value == value) {
        tree->count++;
    }
    else if (strcmp(value, tree->value) < 0) {
        tree_add(tree->left, value);
    }
    else if (strcmp(value, tree->value) > 0) {
        tree_add(tree->right, value);
    }
}

struct tree *new_tree() {
    struct tree * tree;
    tree = malloc(sizeof *tree);
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->value = NULL;
    tree->count = 0;
    return tree;
}
```

The error I get is:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x00000000.

I looked online, and it appears that this error is caused by trying to access improperly allocated memory. So what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATED** code to reflect comments. Now I have a new problem. This condition is not working properly when `value == "x"` and `tree->value == "x"`

```
else if (tree->value == value) {
```

In the debugger, I see that `tree->value` is `0x00553373 "x" char *`, whereas `value` is `0x00553375 "x" char *`. The hex value is different in the last digit. What is wrong here? Am I checking for string equality incorrectly?

Comment: This isn't the solution BUT,
You can't assign values to a NULL pointer as you do in the start of tree_add IF the tree pointer is NULL, also you do not return any pointer from the function even though you specified that the tree_add function should return something?

Comment: Also, where do you malloc the left & right branches? I can't see that anywhere...

Comment: If you have a completely different question, you are supposed to post it disjointly from the first.  Otherwise you are disinclined to accept the answers which solved your problem.  Anyway, don't compare the pointers to the strings, compare the contents -- using strcmp() == 0 as the test.

Comment: visual studio and ultimate are oxymorons

Comment: @Heath ok, I will do that in the future. In the past, I've opened a new question for something I judged to be different from the original issue, and it got votes to be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is this part supposed to work?

```
    if (tree == NULL) {
        tree->value = value;
        tree->count = 0;
    }
```

I ask because what it will do is always attempt to dereference NULL if possible.  The code amounts to:

```
    if (tree == NULL) {
        (NULL)->value = value;
        (NULL)->count = 0;
    }
```

So that is going to receive the AV when it attempts to reach the `value` element of the struct.

I think what you are missing is that you need to call `malloc()` for *each* node in your tree.  You can't call it once at the beginning as you have done here, that only allocates enough memory for one node.

You probably meant something like:

```
    if (tree->left == NULL) {
        tree->left = malloc(sizeof struct tree);
        tree = tree->left;
    }
    /* ... */
```

Then your `tree_free()` function must recursively traverse the tree in depth-first order, calling `free()` on the most leafward elements first, finishing at the root by ultimately freeing the first block you allocated.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (tree == NULL) {
    tree->value = value;
    tree->count = 0;
}
```

there is a problem here, if tree is NULL you can't use it, you must allocate it first

*Additionally, you should store the return value of strcmp instead of doing it twice*

Answer (score 2):

Some problems :

```
tree = malloc(sizeof tree);
```

I think you mean `sizeof *tree` here, you're only allocating space for a pointer
in your code, not for the entire struct.

```
if (tree == NULL) {
    tree->value = value;
    tree->count = 0;
}
```

If tree is NULL then `tree->value` is not ok.

Comment: Heaths answer is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp expects two strings and cannot handle null. Note that `char *c="\0"` is not the same as `char *c = 0`. The first is a pointer to a char array with a single null element, the second is a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You have an improper check in tree_add, here:

```
if (tree == NULL) { 
    tree->value = value; 
    tree->count = 0; 
}
```

Since tree is not-NULL in the original call, you will not write to tree->value and it will stay NULL.  When you then call strcmp, you get the access violation while trying to read from tree->value.

You never actually allocate tree->left and tree->right - you need to allocate these with malloc before using.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments, 'tree_add' needs to return tree and the 'tree_add' calls needs to save that result.  (Although the recursive calls shouldn't save them as tree, but as the left/right pointers).